# Extract values from a parsed json object using a function node or split & switch node in NODE.red

Tags: json, function, nodes, extract

Was trying  to extract values from a parsed json object using a function node or split & switch node, tried to many ways and nothing seems to work fro me.
the example below I would like to have  5 outputs for the text  and numeric values.
here is my payload in json:

```
{
    "applicationID": "1",
    "applicationName": "test_ds18b20",
    "deviceName": "arduino_uno",
    "devEUI": "1234567890123456",
    "rxInfo": [
        {
            "mac": "aa755a0048050130",
            "rssi": -57,
            "loRaSNR": 10,
            "name": "raspberry_pi",
            "latitude": 1.466860686785175,
            "longitude": 2.019478797912605,
            "altitude": 0
        }
    ],
    "txInfo": {
        "frequency": 868100000,
        "dataRate": {
            "modulation": "LORA",
            "bandwidth": 125,
            "spreadFactor": 7
        },
        "adr": true,
        "codeRate": "4/5"
    },
    "fCnt": 9,
    "fPort": 1,
    "data": "Z29vZGJ5ZQ==",
    "object": {}
}
```

first i try with function node to extract "data", but it returns array like this:

```
0: ""data":"Z29vZGJ5ZQ==""
1: "Z29vZGJ5ZQ=="
```

i dont need array i need string
function:

```
var regexsearch = /\"data\":\"(.*?)\"/i;
var my = msg.payload.match(regexsearch);
msg.payload = my;
return msg;
```

but i need to get only this *Z29vZGJ5ZQ==*

than i try with split & switch nodes and gets the whole linelike this: `""data":"Z29vZGJ5ZQ==""`
but i need to get only this *Z29vZGJ5ZQ==*

and here is my flow:

```
[{"id":"d46d38e2.27cc78","type":"inject","z":"ff592a31.cf21a8","name":"","topic":"","payload":"{\"applicationID\":\"1\",\"applicationName\":\"test_ds18b20\",\"deviceName\":\"arduino_uno\",\"devEUI\":\"1234567890123456\",\"rxInfo\":[{\"mac\":\"aa755a0048050130\",\"rssi\":-57,\"loRaSNR\":10,\"name\":\"raspberry_pi\",\"latitude\":48.466860686785175,\"longitude\":35.019478797912605,\"altitude\":0}],\"txInfo\":{\"frequency\":868100000,\"dataRate\":{\"modulation\":\"LORA\",\"bandwidth\":125,\"spreadFactor\":7},\"adr\":true,\"codeRate\":\"4/5\"},\"fCnt\":9,\"fPort\":1,\"data\":\"Z29vZGJ5ZQ==\",\"object\":{}}","payloadType":"json","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":90,"y":160,"wires":[["1a34819e.743eee"]]},{"id":"105db6d9.0df1c9","type":"debug","z":"ff592a31.cf21a8","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"false","x":610,"y":100,"wires":[]},{"id":"1ac8a3e1.8f379c","type":"split","z":"ff592a31.cf21a8","name":"","splt":",","spltType":"str","arraySplt":"1","arraySpltType":"len","stream":false,"addname":"","x":250,"y":340,"wires":[["c10ec515.102d38"]]},{"id":"c10ec515.102d38","type":"switch","z":"ff592a31.cf21a8","name":"","property":"payload","propertyType":"msg","rules":[{"t":"cont","v":"\"data\":","vt":"str"},{"t":"cont","v":"\"latitude\":","vt":"str"}],"checkall":"true","outputs":2,"x":370,"y":340,"wires":[["105db6d9.0df1c9"],["6b2d5d19.7868e4"]]},{"id":"1a34819e.743eee","type":"json","z":"ff592a31.cf21a8","name":"","pretty":false,"x":115.55555555555556,"y":312.22222222222223,"wires":[["1ac8a3e1.8f379c","bae9fa5d.a9f238"]]},{"id":"bae9fa5d.a9f238","type":"function","z":"ff592a31.cf21a8","name":"match","func":"var regexsearch = /\\\"data\\\":\\\"(.*?)\\\"/i;\nvar my = msg.payload.match(regexsearch);\nmsg.payload = my;\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":310,"y":160,"wires":[["105db6d9.0df1c9"]]},{"id":"6b2d5d19.7868e4","type":"debug","z":"ff592a31.cf21a8","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"false","x":610,"y":180,"wires":[]}]
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Why don't you try extracting the value using dot notation or bracket notation ?

Comment: Hassan Imam, you mean something like this msg.payload.data?

Comment: Yes, that will give you 'data' value. I am assuming you have parsed your string to object.